# I would like to return res1 and res but I don't know how. Thank you for your help :)

Tags: javascript

```js
function createInput(text) {
    var regExp = /\{%([^%]+)%\}/g;
    var res = text.replace(regExp, '<input>');

    var regeXp = /dzien_i_miesiac/g;
    var res1 = text.replace(regeXp, '<input type="date">');

    return res1;
}
```

Comment: You can return a Object with res & res1

Comment: try this `return { res1, res }`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning just `res1` you can return an object that contains both `res` and `res1`, for example:

```
function createInput(text){
  var regExp = /\{%([^%]+)%\}/g;
  var res = text.replace(regExp, '<input>');

  var regeXp = /dzien_i_miesiac/g;
  var res1 = text.replace(regeXp, '<input type="date">');

  return { res, res1 };
}
```

And then you could call and the function and get the response as an object:

```
const result = createInput('someText')
console.log(result.res)
console.log(result.res1)
```

or, if you want to use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
const { res, res1 } = createInput('someText')
console.log(res)
console.log(res1)
```